How to manage multiple formset in Django with JavaScript
I have the following problem: I'm loading a form(Form A "Evento") for the User of application fill, in that Form I have to load dynamically another form(Form B "Logistica"), so that the User can add several Form B just clicking the button. I managed to load dynamically these Logistica/Form B for the User, but when I go to the saving part I only managed to receive the fields in a tuple, for example the Form B has a field called "nome", instead of receiving N FormB "nome" fields, I receive only 1 with a [] with the values of each Form. I realize that Django is thinking that instead of N FormB, I have only 1 FormB and it is concatenating the fields
Problem https://github.com/ian-santos-nascimento/Django-event-management
This is my form
 <form method="post" role="form" action="{% url 'evento_create' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.nome.id_for_label }}">Nome</label>
                {{ form.nome }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.descricao.id_for_label }}">Descrição</label>
                {{ form.descricao }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.observacao.id_for_label }}">Observação</label>
                {{ form.observacao }}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="{{ form.local.id_for_label }}">Local</label>
                    {{ form.local }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="{{ form.local.id_for_label }}">Cliente</label>
                    {{ form.cliente }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <label>Comidas</label>
                <div style="height: 30vh;overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #ced4da">
                    {% for comida in comidas %}
                        <div class="pl-3">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="comidas" value="{{ comida.comida_id }}"
                                   class="form-check-input" id="comida-{{ comida.comida_id }}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="comida-{{ comida.comida_id }}">{{ comida.nome }} --
                                R${{ comida.valor }}</label>
                            <div class="quantidade-container" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col">
                    <label for="{{ form.data_inicio.id_for_label }}">Data de Início</label>
                    {{ form.data_inicio }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="{{ form.data_fim.id_for_label }}">Data de Fim</label>
                    {{ form.data_fim }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 id="logistica-title">Logistica</h2>
            {{ logistica_formset.management_form }}
            <div id="logisticas-forms">
                {% for form in logistica_formset %}
                    <div class="logistica-form">
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                        <button type="button" class="remove-logistica btn btn-danger btn-sm  mb-3">Remover</button>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pl-0" id="add-logistica">Adicionar logistica
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>

 <script>
        const addLogisticaButton = document.getElementById('add-logistica');
        const logisticasForms = document.getElementById('logisticas-forms');
        const emptyForm = logisticasForms.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
        const logisticaTitle = document.getElementById('logistica-title');
        const totalFormsInput = document.getElementById('id_logistica-TOTAL_FORMS');

        let formCount = 1;

        addLogisticaButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const newForm = emptyForm.cloneNode(true);
            newForm.style = 'margin-bottom: 30px';
            newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(/__prefix__/g, formCount);
            console.log('emptyForm:', emptyForm);
            console.log('newForm.innerHTML:', newForm.innerHTML);
            logisticasForms.appendChild(newForm);
            updateLogisticaTitleVisibility();
            totalFormsInput.value = logisticasForms.children.length;
            formCount++;
        });

        logisticasForms.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('remove-logistica')) {
                event.target.parentElement.remove();
                updatelogisticaTitleVisibility();
                totalFormsInput.value = logisticasForms.children.length;
            }
        });

        function updatelogisticaTitleVisibility() {
            if (logisticasForms.children.length === 0) {
                logisticaTitle.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                logisticaTitle.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        updatelogisticaTitleVisibility();
    </script>

This is my views for the management of that Form


@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return evento_create_form(request)
    eventos = Evento.objects.only('nome', 'data_inicio', 'local', 'id_evento')
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'eventos': eventos})


@login_required(login_url='login')
def evento_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateEventoForm(request.POST)
        logistica_formset = modelformset_factory(Logistica, CreateLogisticaForm,
                                                 fields=('nome', 'descricao', 'valor', 'dias', 'tipo'),
                                                 extra=request.POST['logistica-TOTAL_FORMS'], )
        logistica_forms = logistica_formset(request.POST, prefix='logistica')
        print(request.POST)
        if logistica_forms.is_valid():
            print(logistica_forms.errors)
            for logistica in logistica_forms:
                print('LOGISTICA'+logistica)
        if form.is_valid():
            evento = form.save(commit=False)
            comidas = criarComidasEvento(form)
            for comida_id, quantidade in comidas.items():
                comida = Comida.objects.get(pk=comida_id)
                evento.save()
                evento.comidas.add(comida, through_defaults={'valor': comida.valor, 'quantidade': quantidade})

            messages.success(request, 'Evento salvo com sucesso!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            message_error(request, form)
            return render(request, 'eventos/novoEvento.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CreateEventoForm()
        return render(request, 'eventos/novoEvento.html', {'form': form, })

def evento_create_form(request):
    form = CreateEventoForm()
    logistica_formset = modelformset_factory(Logistica, CreateLogisticaForm, extra=2)
    logistica_form = logistica_formset(prefix='logistica')
    comidas = Comida.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'eventos/novoEvento.html',
                  {'form': form, 'comidas': comidas, 'logistica_formset': logistica_form})


These are my two forms


class CreateLogisticaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Logistica
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['evento_id']
        widgets = {
            'tipo': forms.Select(),
        }
        labels = {
            'valor': "Valor diária",
            'dias': "Qtd dias"
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.empty_permitted = True


class CreateEventoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    local = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=LocalEvento.objects.all().only('nome').order_by('nome'),
                                   widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    data_inicio = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'mt-3 mb-3 col-3'}))
    data_fim = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'mt-3 mb-3 col-3'}))
    cliente = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cliente.objects.all().only('nome').order_by('nome'),
                                     label='Cliente',
                                     widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Evento
        exclude = ['id_evento']
        fields = ['nome', 'descricao', 'observacao', 'comidas', 'data_inicio', 'local', 'cliente',
                  'data_fim']
        widgets = {
            'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'descricao': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 200px;'}),
            'observacao': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 200px;'}),
            'qtd_dias_evento': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


And finally my model

class Evento(models.Model):
    id_evento = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    observacao = models.TextField()
    comidas = models.ManyToManyField(Comida, through='ComidaEvento')
    qtd_dias_evento = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    local = models.ForeignKey(LocalEvento, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data_inicio = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    data_fim = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        dias = self.data_fim - self.data_inicio
        self.qtd_dias_evento = dias.days
        super(Evento, self).save()


class Logistica(models.Model):
    id_logistica = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    valor = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    dias = models.IntegerField()
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=listSelect.TIPO_LOGISTICA)
    evento_id = models.ForeignKey(Evento, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome



I fixed the problem, I had to refactor my JavaScript, fixed my views.py and create a formset to deal with the forms
views.py:
@login_required(login_url='login')
def evento_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateEventoForm(request.POST)
        logistica_formset = formset_factory(CreateLogisticaForm, formset=CreateLogisticaFormSet,

                                            extra=request.POST['logistica-TOTAL_FORMS'], )
        logistica_forms = logistica_formset(request.POST, prefix='logistica')
        print(request.POST)
        print(f'logistica_formset: {logistica_formset}')
        print(f'logistica_formset.total_form_count: {logistica_formset.total_form_count}')

        evento = form.save(commit=False)
        if form.is_valid() and logistica_forms.is_valid():
            comidas = criarComidasEvento(form)
            for comida_id, quantidade in comidas.items():
                comida = Comida.objects.get(pk=comida_id)
                evento.save()
                evento.comidas.add(comida, through_defaults={'valor': comida.valor, 'quantidade': quantidade})
            for logistica in logistica_forms:
                logistica_obj = logistica.save(commit=False)
                logistica_obj.evento = evento
                logistica_obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Evento salvo com sucesso!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            message_error(request, form)
            return render(request, 'eventos/novoEvento.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CreateEventoForm()
        logistica_formset = CreateLogisticaFormSet(queryset=Logistica.objects.none(), prefix='logistica')
        return render(request, 'eventos/novoEvento.html', {'form': form, 'logistica_formset': logistica_formset})
My forms and formset:

    
class CreateLogisticaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Logistica
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['evento']
        widgets = {
            'tipo': forms.Select(),
        }
        labels = {
            'valor': "Valor diária",
            'dias': "Qtd dias"
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.empty_permitted = True


class CreateEventoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    local = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=LocalEvento.objects.all().only('nome').order_by('nome'),
                                   widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    data_inicio = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'mt-3 mb-3 col-3'}))
    data_fim = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'mt-3 mb-3 col-3'}))
    cliente = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cliente.objects.all().only('nome').order_by('nome'),
                                     label='Cliente',
                                     widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Evento
        exclude = ['id_evento']
        fields = ['nome', 'descricao', 'observacao', 'comidas', 'data_inicio', 'local', 'cliente',
                  'data_fim']
        widgets = {
            'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'descricao': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 200px;'}),
            'observacao': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 200px;'}),
            'qtd_dias_evento': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

CreateLogisticaFormSet = modelformset_factory(Logistica, form=CreateLogisticaForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)

My HTML for the form (only the logistica form):


  <!--GERENCIAR COMIDA QUUANTIDADE -->
    <script>
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="comidas"]');
        checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
            checkbox.addEventListener('change', handleCheckboxChange);
        });

        function handleCheckboxChange(event) {
            const checkbox = event.target;
            const container = checkbox.parentNode.querySelector('.quantidade-container');
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                const input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'number';
                input.name = `quantidade-${checkbox.value}`;
                input.className = 'form-control';
                input.style.width = '60px';
                input.min = '1'; // set the minimum value to 1
                input.style.display = 'inline-block';
                input.style.marginLeft = '10px';
                container.appendChild(input);
            } else {
                container.innerHTML = '';
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function addLogisticaForm() {
            var totalFormsInput = document.getElementById('id_logistica-TOTAL_FORMS');
            var currentValue = parseInt(totalFormsInput.value);
            totalFormsInput.value = currentValue + 1;
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            let formCount = {{ logistica_formset.total_form_count }};
            const logisticaForms = document.getElementById('logisticas-forms');
            const addLogisticaBtn = document.getElementById('add-logistica');

            addLogisticaBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                const newForm = logisticaForms.children[0].cloneNode(true);
                const formRegex = RegExp(`logistica-(\\d){1}-`, 'g');
                console.log("FORM COUNT" + formCount.value)
                formCount.value++;
                newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `logistica-${formCount}-`);
                newForm.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea').forEach(input => {
                    input.value = '';
                    if (input.type === 'checkbox' || input.type === 'radio') {
                        input.checked = false;
                    }
                });
                logisticaForms.appendChild(newForm);
            });

            logisticaForms.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('remove-logistica')) {
                    e.target.parentElement.remove();
                    updateManagementForm();
                }
            });

            function updateManagementForm() {
                const totalForms = document.getElementById('id_logistica-TOTAL_FORMS');
                const currentForms = logisticaForms.querySelectorAll('.logistica-form').length;
                totalForms.value = currentForms;
            }

            updateManagementForm();
        });
    </script>
<h2 id="logistica-title">Logistica</h2>
            {{ logistica_formset.management_form }}
            <div id="logisticas-forms">
                {% for form in logistica_formset %}
                    <div class="logistica-form">
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                        <button type="button" class="remove-logistica btn btn-danger btn-sm  mb-3">Remover</button>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pl-0"
                    id="add-logistica" onclick="addLogisticaForm()">Adicionar logistica
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  



